# Отправить сообщение в заданное время

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, telebot

Здравствуйте! Пишу бота на Python/Telebot. Мне нужно, чтобы каждый день, в 18:00 бот отправлял пользователю определённое сообщение (уведомление). Помогите пожалуйста!
OS: Windows

Comment: Вам поможет cron: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, прошу прощения, мне для Windows.

Comment: Тогда так https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc766428(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два решения:

1. Запускать бота в определенное время с отправкой сообщения. Для Windows можно использовать планировщик задач.
2. Написать скрипт внутри бота, с проверкой времени раз в час и при наступление нужного значения выполняющего отправку.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать модуль schedule [GitHub репозиторий разработчика](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)
Для вашей задачи код будет примерно такой:

```
import schedule

def msg():
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)

schedule.every().day.at("18:00").do(msg)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```